# Need record count for Hadoop batch process

Tags: hadoop, hiveql, batch-processing

I have a hive ql job main.sql called through a shell script main.ksh . The script is scheduled though a cron job running once in a day. I need to capture the number of records processed and inserted to the target table by main.sql in a mysql table for audit purpose. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect output to some file and then grep string like "inserted" on that temp file and then fetch integer using other grep command

Below is sample approch

```
1. Sh myscript.sh > tmp.txt 
2. tmp.txt | grep "insert" | grep -Eo '[0-9] > finalcount.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of table properties given by hive and grep info such as `numRows`.

```
INSERTED_ROWS=$(echo $(hive -e "describe formatted sample_table partition(dt='$DATE_WRITTEN')") 
| grep -o 'numRows.*' 
| awk '{print $3}')
```

If you're not using partitions to insert new data, you can resort to using

```
select COUNT(*) from table where='your_condition'
```

and parse the value.